# If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n f(x,n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n f(x,n)$, what conditions on $f$ allow us to conclude that $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

If we have an equality of the form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n $$
We can conclude that $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$. This can be easily seen by say, differentiating term-wise and showing that $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ and $b_n=\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ for LHS $f$ and RHS $g$.

However, it's clear that in general we do not have for any $f(x,n)$ that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n f(x,n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n f(x,n)
\implies \forall n \ a_n=b_n
\end{equation}

> My question is, what is the most general restrictions we can put on $f$ in order for the implication above to be true?

I can go through some special cases, i.e. polynomials, but I don't believe I have the background to work with general $f$.

I'm in my first undergrad analysis class, so apologies if this is a well-known result.

Comment: If you find this sort of thing interesting, you might find functional analysis (or Fourier analysis) an interesting topic to look into (and pretty commonly taught somewhere in undergrad analysis sequences) - it studies the structures you get by writing functions as (infinite) sums of other functions and the question you ask is often a fairly central concern. (And there's way more subtlety to this question than I think is reasonable to address in an answer on this site - even posing your question formally is troublesome with infinite sums of functions involved!)

Answer (score 2):

Your statement can be reworded:
$$
\sum a_n f(x,n) = \sum b_n f(x,n) \iff \sum (a_n-b_n) f(x,n) = 0,
$$
and you want to conclude that the equality implies $a_n = b_n \iff (a_n-b_n) = 0$, which means $f(x,n)$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: Given the asker's level of experience, it's probably worth noting that by "linearly independent", we here mean that the functions $f(\cdot,n)$ are linearly independent in the vector space of all functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (or, for that matter, functions $A \to B$ with $A$ any set and $B$ any field containing our coefficients), so this is really very general.

Comment: This makes a lot of intuitive sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: These are infinite sums, so it is not exactly linear independence that is required (since linear independence involves only finite sums).

Comment: @GEdgar So what then is the right condition? Or are you saying that this is right but calling it the wrong thing?

Comment: Yes.  You want the condition $(\forall x, \sum_n (a_n-b_n) f(x,n) = 0) \Longrightarrow (\forall n, (a_n-b_n) = 0)$.  But, because the index set is infinite, this is not called "linear independence".

Comment: @GEdgar +1, good eye, appreciate it